# How to do Registration form Validation?

Tags: selenium

I am new to the automation.On the registration form i am trying to insert the username  --> verifying if the validation message populates --> if yes then wants to fail the test case else insert the value in next field

```
public void username(String username1) {
        utils.waitForElements(username, KnowsTestContext.timeout, KnowsTestContext.driver);
        username.sendKeys(username1);
        phonefield.click();

if (usernamevalidation.isEnabled()) {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Continue");
            }
    }

public void phone(String phone1) {
        utils.waitForElements(phone, KnowsTestContext.timeout, KnowsTestContext.driver);
        phone.sendKeys(phone1);
    }
```

Comment: Please add an output from your program and exception message if exists

Answer (score 0):

```
//  if you need to skip test if exist some needs you can use:
    if (some condition){
        throw new SkipException("Test skipped because ...");
    }
//  if you need to stop test if exist some need:
    if (some condition){
        Assert.fail("any message");
    }
// the same for stop test:
    Assert.assertTrue("condition");
```

But in your case you don't need to skip the test, you need create separate tests for check validatio and check login function, besides you need do some changes in your methods, you can try like here:

```
//test for check validation error if try to login with invalid user credentials
@Test
public void checkValidation(){
    driver.get("your_url");
    inputName("not existing username");
    inputPassword("any text");
    clickLoginButton();
    //check if displayed validation error
    Assert.assertTrue(isValidationErrorDisplayed());
}

//test for check login possibility with correct used credentials
@Test
public void loginTest(){
    driver.get("");
    inputName("not existing username");
    inputPassword("any text");
    clickLoginButton();
    //check if occur redirect to welcome page - just as example, in your case it could be another URL
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().endsWith("welcome-page"));
}
```

and methods:

```
//login button is nod defined in your code, you need to add this or use something else
//submit login form
public void clickLoginButton(){
    logineButton.click();
}

//method for fill username to input field
public void inputName(String username1) {
    utils.waitForElements(username, KnowsTestContext.timeout, KnowsTestContext.driver);
    username.sendKeys(username1);
    phonefield.click();



     //this code is redundant in this method, this logic should be in test
//        if (usernamevalidation.isEnabled()) {
//            System.out.println("Failed");
//        } else {
//            System.out.println("Continue");
//        }
}

public boolean isValidationErrorDisplayed(){
    utils.waitForElements(usernamevalidation, KnowsTestContext.timeout, KnowsTestContext.driver);
    return usernamevalidation.isDisplayed();
}

//method for fill password to input field
public void inputPassword(String password) {
    utils.waitForElements(passwordInputField, KnowsTestContext.timeout, KnowsTestContext.driver);
    phone.sendKeys(phone);
}

//method for fill phone to input field
public void inputPhone(String phone) {
    utils.waitForElements(phone, KnowsTestContext.timeout, KnowsTestContext.driver);
    phone.sendKeys(phone);
}
```

hope it's help you

Comment: Thanks.It works.I have used   public void usernameValidation() {
        if (usernamevalidation.isEnabled()) {
            Assert.fail("Test failed! Displayed validation error for username field");
        }  one more question how can i skip this method if username field doesnt get validation message?